# SQL: JOIN value from table A with table C if table B is empty

Tags: sql-server, join

I have three tables and want to join them (inner join) on table A and B matching, however, in the case there is no match for an ID in A, I want to match it to table C instead. Like so:

Table A `person`

```
id   person
1    John
2    Adam
3    Carolin
```

Table B `pet`

```
owner_id  pet
1         Bubbles
3         Fido
```

Table C `vehicle`

```
owner_id  vehicle
2         Mustang
3         Golf
```

The result I would expect would then be

```
person   pet/vehicle
1        Bubbles
2        Mustang
3        Fido
```

for person 3, the pet is selected rather than the vehicle, as the pet is not empty.

I can of course do like this:

```
select a.person,b.pet,c.vehicle from person a
join pet b on a.id = b.owner_id
join vehicle c on a.id = c.owner_id
```

but this would give me three columns, where I need two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE`:

```
select a.person, coalesce(b.pet, c.vehicle) as 'pet/vehicle'
from person a
left join pet b on a.id = b.owner_id
left join vehicle c on a.id = c.owner_id
```

Comment: This looks interesting - I will try this right away